# How to retrieve all users from the logged in user role? - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to retrieve all users from the active user role. I have successfully fetched all the users, but I only want to fetch the users from the currently logged-in user role.

Have the following code in functions to retrieve all users:

```php
// Get users by role
function userLooping( $role ) {
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => $role ) );

    // UserLoop
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) :
        echo '<div id="divuser">';
        foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) :
            echo '<option value="zo">';
            echo $user->display_name; // display user name
            echo '</option>';
        endforeach;
        echo '</div>';
    endif;
}
add_shortcode( 'users_role', 'userLooping' );
```

Note: I only added `<options>` because I'm importing the result into a dropdown.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I also have this in functions to retrieve the logged in users role:

`// Show user role
add_shortcode("um_display_role", function(){
    if( function_exists("um_fetch_user") ){
        um_fetch_user( um_profile_id() );
        return UM()->roles()->get_role_name( um_user("role") );
    }
});`

Comment: What is the result you see when using that shortcode?  

That should work, so I suspect that $role is not defined.  You can test it by hardcoding an actual role name.

Comment: Note: shortcodes should only return the content/output not echo, Check this [WordPress Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output) for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me. A couple of notes:

- You should check to see if the user is logged into WordPress (added in the snippet below)
- Unless you have a good reason to separate it, it makes sense to grab the current user's role in your shortcode function (added in the snippet below)
- A WordPress user can have more than one role, so this uses `role__in` to check an array of roles.
- `<option>` [elements need to be nested inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) a `select`, `outgroup`, or `datalist` elements

```
function userLooping() {
    
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $roles = $user->roles;

        $user_query = new WP_User_Query( [ 'role__in' => $roles ] );
        
        $users = [];

        if ( !empty ( $user_query->results ) ) {
            $users = '<select id="divuser">';
            foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ):
                $users .= "<option value='$user->user_login'>";
                $users .= $user->display_name; // display user name
                $users .= '</option>';
            endforeach;
            $users .= '</select>';

        }
        return $users;
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'users_role', 'userLooping' );
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin! It worked perfectly.
I have more roles for some users, but it seems to pick the first role which is what I want to get. The reason I had made a div was that I already have a select box in my gravity form. So I put the values in a div and then fetched them with javascript. Maybe the wrong way to go? Perhaps it would be best if each user were given a unique value. Now everyone has `<option value="zo">`. Another weird thing I noticed is that when I run this shortcode on a page, the result always ends up at the top left for some reason. All users are installers for a company (role).

Comment: On second thought. Is it possible to get the users from all the roles of the logged in user? Sometimes the administrator of the company needs to edit the posts. That user has two roles. Example: testcompany_admin as first role and testcompany as second role. Unfortunately, Admin must have testcompany_admin as the first role for some other functions on the page to work optimally.

Comment: Note: shortcodes should only return the content/output not echo, Check this [WordPress Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output) for more information on this.

Comment: Thanks for your tip! Will try to learn a little more.

Comment: Tried to make it happen, but unfortunately it doesn't work for admin of the role. Since the admin for the selected company has two roles: testcompany and testcompany_admin, the user only gets himself in the list. Is it possible to make a function that returns all users of both roles? If I log in with a normal user who only has 1 role, it works perfectly.

Comment: You're right vijay-hardaha. I edited the code to return the output. Thanks for catching that.  

@masterior, I edited the code to account for multiple roles.  Now it will show all users who match any of the roles of the current user.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help guys. Appreciate it!

Comment: Hello again! Popping in here again for a moment and see if you guys have any tips. I'm almost done with my page, but I'm stuck on this solution again. When the form is submitted, the answers are saved in a list and in a PDF. But the choice of user is not saved. It is possible to select users when filling out the form, but the result is just "select user" no matter what I do. Is there a way to "hard print" the selection in the select box? Thanks in advance.